# Android Eclipse: multiple debug windows connect to different device instance

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, sms, multiple-instances

I am debugging a sms app.  I can start two emulators.  I can open two debug windows. I can connect both debug windows to open device.  I want to connect one debug window to each different device.  I want to debug the app on both devices.  One device sends SMS and the other receives that SMS. I want to debug sending and receiving at the same time in different debug windows.

Connect one debug window to one device AND connect another debug window to another device. Then send SMS between them.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably not possible at least in Eclipse..

Wait.. I do not know if this will help but if the raw output is not that bad yu could connect to the adb server port that is receiving form that emulator as each emulator is started you get a new adb client on a different port..it be a odd number port usually one up in number form the emulator port number.